# ImportError: cannot import name 'post' from 'request' (C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\request\__init__.py)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to post my code result to an IoT Platform but whenever i'm trying to post the output it's giving me: ImportError: cannot import name 'post' from 'request' (C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\request__init__.py)

is it my package is unusable? or is there any other way to fix this error? 
here is my code

```
hasil = [2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1] 
x = [3,4,2,5,3,4,3,7,6]
import request
from request import post
for e in range (0,len(x)):
            if hasil ==1:
                    q = '{"\nStatus: Tidak Banjir"}'
                    o = json.dumps(q)
                    data = '\r\n{\r\n  "m2m:cin": {\r\n    "cnf": "message",\r\n    "con": "\r\n      {\r\n      \t \\"Status\\": \\"'+str(o)+'\\",\r\n}}}' 
                    url = 'https://platform.antares.id:8443/~/antares-cse/antares-id/FloodForecasting/WeatherData'
                    headers = {'cache-control':'no-cache','content-type':'application/json;ty=4','x-m2m-origin':'7c4f123fd1ba4737:3fc88dbc74b9c905'}
                    r = request.post(url,headers=headers,data=data)
            elif hasil==2:
                    q = '{"\nStatus: Tidak Banjir"}'
                    o = json.dumps(q)
                    #print(o)
                    data = '\r\n{\r\n  "m2m:cin": {\r\n    "cnf": "message",\r\n    "con": "\r\n      {\r\n      \t \\"Status\\": \\"'+str(o)+'\\",\r\n' 
                    url = 'https://platform.antares.id:8443/~/antares-cse/antares-id/FloodForecasting/WeatherData'
                    headers = {'cache-control':'no-cache','content-type':'application/json;ty=4','x-m2m-origin':'7c4f123fd1ba4737:3fc88dbc74b9c905'}
                    r = request.post(url,headers=headers,data=data)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `from request import post` ?

Comment: yes i did, but then the error will be AttributeError: module 'request' has no attribute 'post'

Answer (score 2):

The package name is requests and not request.